# Error using imread function in matlab code

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, matlab, error-handling

I was doing some sort of speech recognition pattern for recognition of sound but I stuck at imread error in matlab, any advice what to change in picture below you can find code and error.

[Code](http://ibb.co/TRfNkyZ)

[Error](http://ibb.co/CJRLGV3)

```
x=audioread ('one.wav');
x1=audioread ('two.wav');
x2=audioread ('three.wav');
x3=audioread ('four.wav');

figure, plot (x);
imwrite (x, 'one.jpg');
figure, plot (x1);
imwrite (x1, 'two.jpg');
figure, plot (x2);
imwrite (x2, 'three.jpg');
figure, plot (x3);
imwrite (x3, 'four.jpg');

AKA = imread ('one.jpg');
AKB = imread ('two.jpg');
AKC = imread ('three.jpg');
AKD = imread ('four.jpg');


AA = rgb2grey(AKA);
AB = rgb2grey(AKB);
AC = rgb2grey(AKC);
AD = rgb2grey(AKD);

aa = imcrop (AA,[200,66,50,300]);
ab = imcrop (AB,[200,66,50,300]);
ac = imcrop (AC,[200,66,50,300]);
ad = imcrop (AD,[200,66,50,300]);

figure, imshow (aa);
figure, imshow (ab);
figure, imshow (ac);
figure, imshow (ad);

p = [aa(75:15:210,:);ab(75:15:210,:);ac(75:15:210,:);ad(75:15:210,:)];
E = double (p');
T = [10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ...
 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 ...
 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 ];
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question as text formatted as code instead of as a picture attachment.

Comment: There it is code